# How can I make a Google Sheets macro to search all rows for a particular fill color, copy the rows and paste them at the bottom of the sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

The rows in my sheet have a fill color in column A of that particular row. I want to be able to use a macro or maybe for loop to search for these rows with the color identifier, copy and paste them below, return to the row where I was and continue the search until the I've hit the bottom of the original list.

- Update -
  Basically I want to start with a sheet like this.

[Google Sheet before macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy7y3.png)

and have the end result look like this

[Google sheet post macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAc6D.png)

Comment: Welcome. Are you familiar with the method 'getBackgrounds' ([ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)). I'd declare a variable for the range occupied by the entire column A and `getBackgrounds` (just like you would `getValues`); then loop through each cell testing for the background. Your statement "copy and paste them below, return to the row where I was" is ambiguous - I have a feeling you mean 'cut and paste' but either way you want to make a note of a matching row and keep incrementing from that row to the pre-existing end of the column.

Comment: Could you show what you tried? Does Tedinoz comment provide a solution to your problem? If that's not the case, please explain what problems you're having. Also, a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on could be useful for people here to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks both your comments helped. I will look into the script you posted and see if that works. I've also updated this post with pictures to better illustrate what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to loop through each row in your sheet and copy/paste the ones which have a certain background color in column A after the last row. If that's the case, then you could use something along the following lines using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) (you would have to create [a script bound to your spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script)):

```js
function appendRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var color = "#582323"; // Please change accordingly
  var firstRow = 1;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var column = 1;
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn() - column + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, numRows); // Get column A
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds(); // Get backgrounds of each cell in column A
  for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) { // Iterate through each cell in column A
    if (backgrounds[i][0] == color) { // Check background color
      var rowToCopy = sheet.getRange(i + 1, column, 1, numCols); // Row to be copied
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Row index to copy to
      rowToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, column, 1, numCols)); // Copy row to the bottom
    }
  }
}
```

#### Notes:

- Please change the background color you want to look for.
- Check inline comments for more information on what the script is doing, line by line.

#### Reference:

- [getBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

I hope this is of any help.